# jQuery, doing something after scrolling

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to get the percentage scrolled in a html document ?

I want to hide some divs if the user scrolls 200px to the bottom direction

I tried :

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    st=jQuery(window).scroll();
    jQuery('#wrap').html(st)


    if(st>200){
        if(flag)
        alert('test');
    }

});
```

I guess there is also a performance problem because of the high res mouse (3500dpi in my case) the amount of errors on the console is about 100 !

And i dosent work

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what the 200px indicates, but `.scroll()` triggers the scroll event; it doesn't get the position.  For that you want [`scrollTop`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/):

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    st=jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    jQuery('#wrap').html(st)    

    if(st>200){
        if(flag)
        alert('test');
    }

});
```